# What stream format should iOS5 Effect Units use

Tags: ios, signal-processing, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to use a Low Pass Filter AU. I keep getting a kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported (-10868) error when setting the stream format to the filter unit, but if I just use the Remote IO unit there's no error.

The stream format I'm using is (Updated):

```
myASBD.mSampleRate = hardwareSampleRate;
myASBD.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;      
myASBD.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;
myASBD.mBitsPerChannel = 8 * sizeof(float);
myASBD.mFramesPerPacket = 1;                                          
myASBD.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;           
myASBD.mBytesPerPacket = sizeof(float) * myASBD.mFramesPerPacket;                                                                            
myASBD.mBytesPerFrame = sizeof(float) * myASBD.mChannelsPerFrame;
```

And I'm setting the filter stream like this:

```
 // Sets input stream type to ASBD
 setupErr = AudioUnitSetProperty(filterUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &myASBD, sizeof(myASBD));
 NSLog(@"Filter in: %i", setupErr);

 //NSAssert(setupErr == noErr, @"No ASBD on Finput");


//Sets output stream type to ASBD
setupErr = AudioUnitSetProperty(filterUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &myASBD, sizeof(myASBD));
NSLog(@"Filter out: %i", setupErr);
NSAssert(setupErr == noErr, @"No ASBD on Foutput");
```

Answer (score 3):

The canonical format for iOS filter audio units is 8.24 fixed-point (linear PCM), which is 32 bits per channel, not 16.

Comment: I've tried using 32 bit channels and I still get stream format errors. I've been told elsewhere that the built in AU effects in iOS5 don't use a canonical format too..
I've tried getting the stream format from the filter unit using AudioUnitGetProperty but every time I try I receive an error.
Would it be a better idea to use a render callback and just use the current ASBD?

Comment: Did you set the type fixed-point or float?  That's one difference between canonical format on Mac versus iOS.

Comment: I've changed it so I'm not using a float, but I'm still getting the error. I'm not sure whether I'm setting the filter ASBD correctly as this is where I get the error.

Answer (score 2):

what format is working wit the reverb unit??? I'm getting weird errors tryn to record a buffer....any news on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the canonical format.

> ```
> size_t bytesPerSample = sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType); //Default is 4 bytes
> myASBD.mSampleRate        = hardwareSampleRate;
> myASBD.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
> myASBD.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical; //Canonical AU format
> myASBD.mBytesPerPacket    = bytesPerSample;
> myASBD.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
> myASBD.mBytesPerFrame     = bytesPerSample;
> myASBD.mChannelsPerFrame  = 2;  //Stereo
> myASBD.mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * bytesPerSample;  //32bit integer
> ```

You will need to make sure all your AudioUnits ASBDs are configured uniformly.

If you are doing heavy audio processing, floats (supported in iOS5) is not a bad idea too.

> ```
> size_t bytesPerSample     = sizeof (float); //float is 4 bytes
> myASBD.mSampleRate        = hardwareSampleRate;
> myASBD.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
> myASBD.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat;
> myASBD.mBytesPerPacket    = bytesPerSample;
> myASBD.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
> myASBD.mBytesPerFrame     = bytesPerSample;
> myASBD.mChannelsPerFrame  = 2;
> myASBD.mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * bytesPerSample;  //32bit float
> ```